# C++ - JSON::Value use as resference in function parameter

Tags: c++, json

How do I use from JSON::Value with pointer in function?

Update:

```
string sign_pkcs(int tab)
{
    Json::Value json_output;
    json_output["tab"] = tab;

    add_to_json_string(&json_output, "find_certificate_object", "Find certificate successfully!");


    >> This is using from json_output

    return ...
}

void add_to_json_string(Json::Value *jsonInput, string key, string value)
{
    *jsonInput[key] = value;
}
```

but I get error:

```
Error (active)  E0349   no operator "[]" matches these operands
```

I want to add any key and value from other function to one JSON variable in every step of my code.

Comment: Why are you using a pointer to this object instead of a reference, anyways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]` has higher priority than `*`, so you need to do `(*jsonInput)[key]`.